# K-neighbors example with Python by computing matrix of square distance

Tags: python, data-science

I am reading a textbook where it is analyzing how to find the nearest neighbors. What confuses me is a code that computes the differences in coordinates, the code is attached. What confuses me is why you have to add a new dimension via np.newaxis to compute the differences?

```
dist_sq= np.sum((X[:, np.newaxis,:] - X[np.newaxis,:,:])**2, axis -1)
```

Comment: can you point us to the text book or copy the entire code?

Comment: Thanks, see here starting In[15]: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.08-sorting.html